# Safe low 32 bits masking of uint64_t

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, 64-bit, implicit-conversion, bitmask

Assume the following code:

```
uint64_t g_global_var;

....
....

void foo(void)
{
    uint64_t local_32bit_low = g_global_var & 0xFFFFFFFF;
    ....
}
```

With the current toolchain, this code works as expected, `local_32bit_low` indeed contains the low 32 bits of `g_global_var`.

I wonder if it is guaranteed by the standard C that this code will always work as expected?
My concern is that the compiler may treat 0xFFFFFFFF as integer value of -1 and when promoting to `uint64_t` it would become 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

**P.S.**

I know that to be on the safe side it is better to use 0xFFFFFFFFULL in this case. The point is that I saw it in a legacy code and I wonder if it worth to be fixed or not.

Comment: _My concern is that the compiler may treat 0xFFFFFFFF as integer value of -1_ , why would the compiler do that?

Comment: @DavidRanieri Because constant numbers by default have type of `int` and in 2th complementary, 0xFFFFFFFF is -1 (for `int`s)

Comment: @DavidRanieri because technically all integer constants are signed (with caveats) unless suffixed with a `u`

Comment: @Mgetz Not true.  All *decimal* integer constants are signed unless otherwise specified with a suffix, but *octal* or *hexadecimal* constants can be unsigned.  In this particular case, it would be unsigned, as per the C standard included in Vlad's answer.

Comment: Technically, there is no such thing as a negative integer constant.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons those are the caveats, but that's implementation dependent and not guaranteed in all cases. However the core of it is that in almost all cases it's not worth worrying about because of how all integer constants, even decimals, are positive by default and negation is applied afterwards.

Comment: Just cast it to `unsigned` if you're worried about it.

Comment: @Mgetz The issue I have is that this question is specifically about hexadecimal representation, so sweeping that under the rug as a "caveat" isn't very helpful and potentially misleading as it pertains to this question.  I will agree, though, that the specific type isn't as important to the OP's issue so much as the fact that integer constants are always positive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no problem. The integer constant `0xFFFFFFFF` has the type that is able to store the value as is.

According to the C Standard (6.4.4.1 Integer constants)

> 5 The type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding
>   list in which its value can be represented

So this value is stored as a positive value.

If the type `unsigned int` is a 32-bit integer type then the constant will have the type `unsigned int`.

Otherwise it will have one of the types that can store the value.

```
long int
unsigned long int
long long int
unsigned long long int
```

Due to the usual arithmetic conversions in the expression

```
g_global_var & 0xFFFFFFFF;
```

it is promoted like

```
0x00000000FFFFFFFF
```

Pay attention to that in C there is no negative integer constants. For example an expression like

```
-10
```

consists of two sub-expressions: the primary expression `10` and the sub-expression with the unary operator `-` `-19` that coincides with the full expression.

Comment: It could have type `int` if `int` is more than 32 bits wide.

Comment: @IanAbbott The size of int can not be greater than the size of unsigned int.:)

Comment: True, but who says size 4 means 32 bits?

Comment: @IanAbbott We do not deep into details about that some implementations can have padding bits.:)

Comment: I wasn't referring to the padding bits. :) E.g. you could have a 9-bit `char` and a 36-bit `int`.

Comment: Hmm, I want to agree with @IanAbbott, who is technically correct (best kind of correct) that if CHAR_BIT is not 8, then it could still be an `int`, even if `unsigned int` has sizeof 4.  But on the other hand, if `CHAR_BIT` is 9, then you wouldn't have `uint64_t` available, which is the type of `g_global_var`, therefore it can be surmised that `CHAR_BIT` is not, in fact, 9.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons That's a good point, but my point would still apply if `CHAR_BIT` is 16 and `unsigned int` is 64 bits wide.

Comment: @IanAbbott Agreed.  That is why I restricted my comment to the example of `CHAR_BIT` being 9 rather than specifying that `CHAR_BIT` must therefore be 8 making it a non-factor.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Understood. :)

Answer (score 3):

0xffffffff is not -1, ever. It may convert to -1 if you cast or coerce (e.g. by assignment) it to a signed 32-bit type, but integer literals in C always have their mathematical value unless they overflow.

For decimal literals, the type is the narrowest signed type that can represent the value. For hex literals, unsigned types are used before going up to the next wider signed type. So, in the common case where `int` is 32-bit, 0xffffffff would have type `unsigned int`. If you wrote it as decimal, it would have type `long` (if `long` is 64-bit) or `long long` (if `long` is only 32-bit).

Answer (score 1):

The type of an unsuffixed hexadecimal or octal constant is the first of the following list in which its value can be represented:

```
int
unsigned int
long int
unsigned long int
long long int
unsigned long long int
```

(For unsuffixed decimal constants, remove the `unsigned` types from the above list.)

The hexadecimal constant `0xFFFFFFFF` can definitely be represented by `unsigned long int`, so its type will be the first of `int`, `unsigned int`, `long int` or `unsigned long int` that can represent its value.

Note that although `0xFFFFFFFF > 0` always evaluates to 1 (true), it is possible for `0xFFFFFFFF > -1` to evaluate to either 0 (false) or 1 (true) on different implementations. So you need to be careful when comparing integer constants with each other or with other objects of integer type.

Answer (score 0):

Others have answered the question, just a recomendation, next time (if you are under C11) you can check the type of the expression by yourself using `_Generic`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define print_type(x) _Generic((x), \
    int64_t:  puts("int64_t"),      \
    uint64_t: puts("uint64_t"),     \
    default:  puts("unknown")       \
)

uint64_t g_global_var;

int main(void)
{
    print_type(g_global_var & 0xFFFFFFFF);
    return 0;
}
```

The ouput is

```
uint64_t
```